# IBM Containers: Unable to login with "cf ic login"

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

While trying to remove an image (name: defaultimage) from my Bluemix container repository with

```
cf ic rmi registry.ng.bluemix.net/XXX/defaultimagename
```

I receive the message:

```
Command failed - Could not connect to IBM Containers
{"error": "Tag not found"}
```

When I try to login to containers with "cf ic login" I get this error:

```
** Retrieving client certificates from IBM Containers
** Storing client certificates in /home/uebele/.ice/certs
Successfully retrieved client certificates
** Authenticating with registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net
Could not authenticate with IBM Containers registry at registry.ng.bluemix.net
**** exit status 1
****time="2015-08-26T14:04:44+02:00" level=fatal 
msg="Error response from daemon: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n
<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.
If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a temporary outage, please try again later.

Try the following sequence.

```
cf login 
cf ic login
```